# Global dependency check on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to do some cleanup in an existing database.
I know how I can check if a view/table/SP has any dependencies before deleting it. However the dependency list completely ignores calls from the SQL Server Agent job steps, for instance.
Is there any code or tool that would allow doing for a **complete** dependency check of objects, including SSA jobs ?
I am using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Red Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which includes jobs. And it is free

Comment: I already use it, and it is incredibly usefull. I was just wondering if there was someting that would do a global

Answer (score 1):

"Complete dependency check" would mean any client app, scheduled (with not only sql agent) scripts, SSIS packages, so - no.

To search on sql server by yourself you may try investigating:

`sys.sqlmodules->definition`, `dbo.sysjobsteps->command`.